# Getting values from checkboxes using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having a problem trying to get the value from checked `checkbox`es. I can get a value from the `radio button`s, but I cannot get a value from the checkboxes.

Code

```
<html>
<head>
    <script language="javascript">

        function subscription() {
            var subamount = document.querySelector('input[name="sublvl"]:checked').value;
            $('input:checked').each(function () {
                // To pass this value to its nearby hidden input
                $(this).parent('td').next('input').val($(this).val());
            });

            alert(subamount);
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>
        <span style="color: #ff0000;">Step 1: Choose your donation amount</span></h3>
    <form name="pclvl" action="#" method="get">
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="sublvl" value="10" />
        Pathfinder Chronicler Supporter $10.00 USD</label>
    <br>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="sublvl" value="15" />
        Pathfinder Chronicler Bronze Supporter $15.00 USD</label>
    <br>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="sublvl" value="20" />
        Pathfinder Chronicler Silver Supporter $20.00 USD</label>
    <br>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="sublvl" value="30" />
        Pathfinder Chronicler Gold Supporter $30.00 USD</label>
    <br>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="sublvl" value="40" />
        Pathfinder Chronicler Platinum Supporter $40.00 USD</label>
    <br>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="sublvl" value="45" />
        Pathfinder Chronicler Jewel Supporter $45.00 USD</label>
    <br>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="sublvl" value="50" />
        Pathfinder Chronicler Diamond Supporter $50.00 USD</label>
    <br>
    </p>
    </form>
    <h3>
        <span style="color: #ff0000;">Step 2: Choose your donation reward</span></h3>
    <p>
        <form name="donations" action="#" method="get">
        <input type="checkbox" name="reward" value="1" />
        Vol. I Package ($10 value) A print copy of Pathfinder Chronicler Volume I (shipping
        charges not included)<br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="reward" value="2" />
        Vol. II Package ($10 value) A print copy of Pathfinder Chronicler Volume II (shipping
        charges not included)
        <br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="reward" value="3" />
        Vol. III Package ($10 value) A print copy of Pathfinder Chronicler Volume III (shipping
        charges not included)
        <br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="reward" value="4" />
        Vol. I Package + Vol. I Poster ($15 value) A print copy of Pathfinder Chronicler
        Volume I with a 11x17 Poster of Volume I Source Art by Eva Widermann (shipping charges
        not included)<br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="reward" value="5" />
        Vol. II Package + Vol. II Poster ($15 value) A print copy of Pathfinder Chronicler
        Volume II with a 11x17 Poster of Volume II Source Art by Carolina Eade (shipping
        charges not included)<br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="reward" value="6" />
        Vol. III Package + Vol. III Poster ($15 value) A print copy of Pathfinder Chronicler
        Volume II with a 11x17 Poster of Volume III Source Art by Carolina Eade (shipping
        charges not included)<br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="reward" value="7" />
        Complete Package ($50 value) Print copies of Pathfinder Chronicler Volume I, II
        and III with 11x17 Posters of Volume I, II, III, and IV Source Art, by Eva Widermann
        and Carolina Eade (shipping charges not included)<br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="poster" value="poster" />
        Poster Package ($20 value) 11x17 Posters of Volume I, II, III, and IV Source Art,
        by Eva Widermann and Carolina Eade (shipping charges not included)<br />
    </p>
    <input type="button" value="test click" onclick="subscription(this.form)">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `.next('input')` should probably be `.next('input:hidden')`. But why are you duplicating that anyway, aren't your checkboxes submitted?

Comment: How do you intend to handle multiple selections of the `reward`?

Comment: Why are you using both jQuery *and* native DOM selectors?

Comment: In this line: `$(this).parent('td').next('input').val($(this).val());` You are looking for a parent `<td>` element, but your html doesn't have any `<td>` elements.

Comment: ok, I am sorry i have been away from from web programming from awhile. what is the best way to go about this.

Comment: jQuery != Javascript -- the title to the question is a little misleading

Comment: What would you expect the value of a checkbox to be?  A checkbox's status is more or less a boolean... and checkboxes have a property "this.checked" that is 1 or 0.  Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to use jQuery, may as well stick to jQuery. I am including plenty of comments since you have been away from web programming for a while and might use the refresher.

**Edit: Just saw your edit, changed to get the checkboxes**

```
function subscription() {

    // Create an array of checkbox inputs that are checked
    var $inputs = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');

    // Iterate through all the checked inputs, you could use
    // jQuery's $each here but it's horribly slow
    for (var i = 0; i < $inputs.length; i++) {

        // Assign the value
        var inputValue = $($inputs[i]).val();

        // Please note I cannot see the hidden field on your markup, but let's
        // just target the first hidden field available if that is what you want
        // If you include the hidden field on the markup, we could target it
        // specifically also...
        $('input:hidden').val(inputValue);

    }
}
```

Comment: how would i output these then?

Comment: ok let me ask you this i need to get the info from the radio buttons and the checkboxes and then send to paypal what is the best way to do this, with out leaving the page.